# Current time and current time + 10 mins in number

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, time, jwt

Im try to set an issued time and an expiry time for my jwt . I cant seem to get the dates right . Either they are too far off or not integers at all . I want to achieve this without using moment.js . This is what i got so far (which is also not correct).

```
 const payload = {
  // issued at time
  iat: currentDate.getTime() / 1000,
  // JWT expiration time (10 minute maximum)
  exp: new Date(currentDate.getTime() + 10 * 60000).getTime() / 1000,
  // GitHub App's identifier
};
```

Comment: This is what i got -> { iat: 1606907590.064, exp: 1606908190.064, iss: 74401289 } payload

Comment: And this was the error ->  "'Expiration time' claim ('exp') must be a numeric value representing the future time at which the assertion expires"

Comment: Logging `new Date(payload.exp * 1000)` gives a timestamp 10 minutes from now, as expected. Are you supposed to use second-based timestamps?

Comment: Try using `Math.floor()` on the values so they're integers.

Comment: What about `const currTime = Date.now();

const payload = {
  iat: currTime,
  exp: currTime + (10 * 60 * 1000)
}` ?

Comment: read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60977764/add-8-hours-to-the-token-issuance-date/60978048#60978048) about the number format that you need in a JWT

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add 8 hours to the token issuance date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60977764/add-8-hours-to-the-token-issuance-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JWTs want UNIX timestamps ... seconds since `1970-01-01T00:00Z`.

You get those from Javascript timestamps by doing stuff like this:

```
const nowTime = Math.floor(Date.now() * 0.001)
```

Javascript timestamps are UNIX timestamps in milliseconds, not seconds.

And of course 10min is 600s. So you should be able to do this to get your start and expiry times.

```js
 const nowTime = Math.floor(currentDate.getTime() / 1000)
 const payload = {
  iat: nowTime,
  exp: 600 + nowTime
 }
```

No moment.js required.